# Memory leak when move function to thread (using lambda)

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-leaks

I have the code below, which uses [uWebSockets](https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets) as the library for my backend. Now I want to shut down properly, it leads to memory leak (using **valgrind** to check).

```cpp
#include <App.h>

#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    us_listen_socket *token{};

    auto start_server = [&token] {
        uWS::App()
            .listen(9001, [&token](auto *listenSocket) {
                if (listenSocket) token = listenSocket;
            })
            .run();
    };

    auto start_timer = [&token] {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
        us_listen_socket_close(token);
    };

    ...
}
```

`...` is as follow:

Leaked version:

```cpp
std::thread(start_server).detach();
start_timer();
```

Leak free version:

```cpp
std::thread(start_timer).detach();
start_server();
```

I know the program only leaks when I move the code for running the server to a seperate thread but I can't reason about the cause of this.

Comment: Not related to your issue, but starting a thread and immediately detach it is probably never the right thing to do. Using detach at all is almost never a good idea.

Comment: i understand that's can be a problem but since I want a compiled and runnable version of my code, using detach gives the shortest version. But thank you for mentioning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, then both versions have undefined behavior because you have two threads that concurrently access the object `token`, one of which is writing to it while the other one is reading from it. I'm not sure what exactly the purpose of attempting to close `token` after precisely 2 seconds is supposed to be; but whatever it is, you will have to use proper synchronization, e.g., using [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) to protect the access to `token`, or at least make `token` [atomic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic). The program will then continue to leak, since that only depends on whether it happens to take longer than 2 seconds for someone to connect (I presume that's what's going on here) or not, but at least the leaking will be well-defined behavior…